# Android Compose LazyScrollState properties causing recomposition of the LazyColumn items

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

I have been using the properties `firstVisibleItemIndex` and `firstVisibleItemScrollOffset` from `LazyListState` in order to know when to show a button.

So I have something like this:

```
@Composable
fun MyComposable(
   onScroll: (firstVisibleItemIndex, firstVisibleItemScrollOffset) -> Unit
) {
   
   val lazyScrollState = rememberLazyListState()
   
   LaunchedEffect(
      lazyScrollState.firstVisibleItemIndex,
      lazyScrollState.firstVisibleItemScrollOffset
   ) {
      onScroll(firstVisibleItemIndex, firstVisibleItemScrollOffset)
   }

   LazyColumn(state = lazyScrollState) {
      items()
   }
}
```

After analysing the Layout Inspector, I noticed that many recompositions of the items of the LazyColumn are happening when scrolling, which doesn't happen if I remove the `LaunchedEffect` code. My first assumption was that the call `onScroll` was causing the issue, however, even if I leave `LaunchedEffect` empty, the recompositions still happen, which made me realize that the recompositions were provoked by the use of `firstVisibleItemIndex` and `firstVisibleItemScrollOffset` itself, not the code executed by `onScroll`.

I also tried using other performance techniques for Jetpack Compose, like the use of `derivedStateOf` for those fields and even externalise the logic out of the composable, but none of them was successful. Does anyone have any clue?

Answer (score 0):

This should be solved with `derivedStateOf`, if it didn't work for you, you might have used it incorrectly - post the code. The point is that with your code, the composable recomposes with every tiny scroll, because `firstVisibleItemScrollOffset` changes. With `derivedStateOf`, it will recompose only when the visibility of the button should change.

It should look like this - note that it's important to `remember` the derived state:

```
val isButtonVisible by remember {
    derivedStateOf {
        // whatever logic you need
        lazyScrollState.firstVisibleItemIndex > 0 ||
        lazyScrollState.firstVisibleItemScrollOffset > 0
    }
}
```